# How to add copyright notice and vesion information to DLL using autotools

Tags: dll, autotools

How do I make autotools (or libtool) to add file version, product name, product version, copyright, etc. to windows DLLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autotools will not do this for you.  All that info (Copyright, et al.) is in a resource (`.rc`) file.  The resource file needs to be compiled with the [windres](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MS_resource_compiler) binutil and linked with the DLL.  There might even be a builtin rule on the Windows version of GNU make to assist in this process.  If not, you can easily write a make rule to do so.

The upshot of all this information is: add the .rc file to the DLL's `libfoo_SOURCES`.  If it works, congratulations!  If not, you'll have to diagnose the problem at the point of failure.

Answer (score 1):

Windows resource files appear to be a supported [tag](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Tags) for libtools. Add the resource file, say, `foorc.rc` to `libfoo_la_SOURCES` in `Makefile.am` to generate a `.lo` libtool object, as with C source files.

This may (or may not) require an explicit rule, e.g.,

```
.rc.lo:
        $(LIBTOOL) --tag=RC --mode=compile windres $< -o $@
```